# Need good source for learning Omnet++

Tags: omnet++

I am new to omnet++ simulator. The videos on youtube are not that helpful as would be for learning java or c or c++. Can someone suggest me a good source for learning omnet++(**especially in domain of WSN attack by node capturing**)

Answer (score 2):

The [OMNeT++ website's "documentation" page](https://omnetpp.org/documentation) has a variety of excellent learning material available: from a high level introduction in the shape of a flow chart, to a PDF user manual, to an API reference, to a "ten minute" introduction and screencast, and to excellent hands-on tutorials.

I would recommend to start with the user manual which covers everything from basic to advanced concepts and implementation details. In parallel I would recommend doing the Tic Toc tutorial.

Comment: That is correct. After learning OMNeT++, you will most likely want to use an existing simulation module library (see https://omnetpp.org/models) so that you do not need to create a model of a WSN yourself. The available model libraries differ in what they focus on (overlay network aspects, transport/network layer aspects, physical layer aspects). Some are quite similar in their structure, some are vastly different. So, after learning OMNeT++, your next task will be to pick which simulation model library is right for you - and then to learn how to use this library.

Comment: How do you suggest I do that?

Comment: I don't quite understand. What do you mean by "that"? Learn?